# R lidR segment trees using Dalponte algorithm

Tags: r, lidr

When I run the code provided below, I get the following warning message.

How I can resolve this error, as this message is returning `segment_trees` with zero trees?

Message:

```
In CPL_write_gdal(mat, file, driver, options, type, dims, from,  :
  GDAL Message 1: Setting GeoTIFF 1.1 requires libgeotiff >= 1.6. Key values will be written as GeoTIFF 1.1, but the version number will be seen as 1.0, which might confuse GeoTIFF readers
```

Code:

```
library(lidR)

algo1 = dalponte2016(chm_p2r_05_smoothed, ttops_chm_p2r_05_smoothed)
las = segment_trees(las, algo1, attribute = "IDdalponte")
```

Please note that I don't get this message while using `segment_trees` with `li2012` and `silve2016`.

Comment: No idea, never seen that especially no raster is expected to be written here. What I'm sure however is that this issue is OS and/or version specific. So you must report a fully reproducible exemple including data, OS, terra version, lidr version, the output of `library(sf)` and anything else that may be useful. And I think it is more a bug that must be reported than an actual question to be asked here.

Comment: @JRR thank you, unfortunately I can't share the data due to work policies, however I can share the code and the rest of the things `lidR/github`, will that work?

Comment: You can certainly reproduce with other data